# Why can't I access my Refinery CMS route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I have the following routes in Refinery:

```
$ rake routes | grep blog
                                 blog_root        /blog(.:format)                                                      refinery/blog/posts#index
                                 blog_post GET    /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                                            refinery/blog/posts#show
...
```

However, when I try to access that route, it gives an error.

```
 >   app.refinery.blog_post_path
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"refinery/blog/posts"}
```

Here is part of routes.rb

```
  # Refinery
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: '/'
```

Rails 3.2.14, Refinery 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Two things spring to mind

1. You probably don't need to preface `refinery.blog_post_path` with `app` although that doesn't seem to be the source of your error.
2. More importantly, you have not specified which blog post you want to show. So, your code should look something like `refinery.blog_post_path my_blog_post.id`